# Add page numbers to pdf using pagedown::chrome_print (R package)?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, slidy

I am using `pagedown::chrome_print()` to convert slidy presentations created with Rmarkdown to pdf -- it does a better job than saving as PDF from Chrome.  However, despite studying the help file, I cannot figure out how to add page numbers. Is there a way to do this?

(Note that pagedown here refers to the R package, not the JavaScript markdown previewer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry if the help page is not clear on this point.

It is possible to pass header/footer options to Chrome using `pagedown::chrome_print()`.

These options are the ones defined by the Chrome DevTools Protocol for the [Page.printToPDF method](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-printToPDF).

You can customise the header and the footer with an HTML template. Chrome also offers the following values: `date`, `title`, `url`, `pageNumber` and `totalPages`.

Following the explanations on this help page, here is an example to print the page numbers:

```
library(htmltools)

footer <- div(
  style = "font-size: 8pt; text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 12pt;", 
  span(class = "pageNumber"), "/", span(class = "totalPages")
)

pagedown::chrome_print(
  "slidy.Rmd", 
  options = list(
    landscape = TRUE, 
    displayHeaderFooter = TRUE, 
    footerTemplate = format(footer, indent = FALSE),
    marginTop = 0,
    marginBottom = 0.4
  )
)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was hoping existed.

Comment: Note: at least for my purposes, `slidy.Rmd` should be `slidy.html`.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work with a custom CSS file. I created a file called `custom.css` and included in that file was

```
@page  {
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page);
  }
}
```

Then I used that along with the other pagedown defaults with a header like this

```
title: "My Report"
output:
  pagedown::html_paged: 
    css: ["custom.css", "default-fonts", "default"]
```

Comment: Doesn't that produce html output?

Comment: Well, pagedown works by making html and then printing to pdf through a web browser. At least that’s how I understand how it works.

Comment: I think that's right. So the idea would be to add numbers with `html_paged` (or perhaps directly through slidy options) and then use `chrome_print`?

Comment: I mean I used exactly this and I got page numbers in my output. Not sure if there was another way.

Comment: The problem is that the output that `pagedown::html_paged` produces is formatted very differently from the `slidy_presentation` output. I'm going to need to find a way to either add page numbers to the original slidy slides, or perhaps later to the pdf rendered with `pagedown::chrome_print`.